# Getting element by class name with jQuery doesn`t work when element is in ng-repeat directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i would like to access div in ng-repeat directive with jQuery,but problem is i got undefined.When i remove ng-repeat directive it`s working fine.Is there any solution for this?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="showAdmins" ng-show="showAdmins">
    <div class="card card-block" ng-repeat="admin in showAdmins  track  by $index" style="float: left;margin: 30px; background: #fff;">
        <h3 class="card-title">{{admin}}</h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="searchAdmins(admin)">See Profile</button>
    </div>
```

And controller:

```
(function(){       
    var cardBox = $('.card.card-block');

    console.log(cardBox[0]);
    for(var i=0; i<cardBox.length;i++){           
        cardBox[i].style.padding = '15px';
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-style, because i don't see any case for using jQuery in your code!